# How to destructure an Array from an Object in Redux React?

Tags: redux, react-redux, dispatch, destructure

I am using redux and I want to destructure **teamMembers - Array** from an **Object name - teamData** which I am getting from REDUX. This is what I have done below. I just want to confirm whether is this the right way to do.

```
  const teamData = useSelector((state) => state.team.teamData);
  const { description, heading } = teamData;
  const teamMembers = useSelector((state) => state.team.teamData.teamMembers);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, you should **not** do

```js
  const teamData = useSelector((state) => state.team.teamData);
  const { description, heading } = teamData;
```

Your code here is interested in `description` and `heading`, but your `useSelector` selects the whole `teamData`.
Now, if there is a third property on `teamData`, let's say `winStreak` and that `winStreak` changes, your component will rerender. Because that change to `winData.teamStreak` caused `winData` to change. And your `useSelector` is watching `winData` for changes.

If you instead do

```js
const description = useSelector((state) => state.team.teamData.description);
const heading = useSelector((state) => state.team.teamData.heading );
```

your component will *only* rerender, when `description` or `heading` change. Because your `useSelector` now watches those two properties for changes. It does not care if `teamData` changes, it only cares if teamData.description`or`teamData.heading` change.

So, in your case you should do

```js
const description = useSelector((state) => state.team.teamData.description);
const heading = useSelector((state) => state.team.teamData.heading );
const teamMembers = useSelector((state) => state.team.teamData.teamMembers );
```

and not use any destructuring here.
If you have to destructure the result of a `useSelector` call, that likely means that your `useSelector` call is also observing data you are not interested in in the first place.

Comment: Thank you so much for your support. Now I understand how to use it.